# Store files to Google cloud from Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to store my SD card contents to Google docs (or any Google cloud service) and retrieve them from there via an Android device.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best place is to go here http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

You will find examples there on how to programmatically get access to [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can use http library available in Android for accomplishing cloud communication via Android. Android has the Apache http library in its runtime. So you can rely on that. I have written a cloud based app. Hope this [little blog](http://pgopinath.wordpress.com/) can help you

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you need, but real cloud storage at [Google Storage for Developers](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/) can be easily and securely accessed using [jetS3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) (pronounced "jetset").  The icing is that jetset also is compatible with Amazon S3 cloud storage!